# Atata: Disabled Control

Tags: atata

How can I work with a disabled control (gets enabled later due to a certain action)?

We have a page (Page1) on the application which has a button (LoadPage2) disabled when a user accesses the page and enabled once user upload a file on Page1.

Can you please explain the best way to add these controls in the page object model?

When I add the button on POM for Page 1, it give an exception when users go to Page 1.

Comment: Mukul, could you share a code of your page object? Also, please share an exception. It may be that you have defined property incorrectly. Upon page object initialization during navigation control states (visible, enabled) are not checked, but can be checked when you directly appeal to the particular control.

Comment: [FindById("btnLaunchW")]
        public Control<_> BtnLaunchWorkpaper { get; private set; }

Comment: Property looks OK. Ensure that _ is the correct page object type where the property is located. And please share an exception that you receive.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried few times and not getting any error now. Still learning various Wait Options :). BTW, thanks for creating great framework.